# Loop over each list item in the above JSFiddle and do the following:

Tags: javascript, html

[https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/gSchool/g67_fiddles/tree/master/dom-looping][1]

```
When you get to the page, press the "Run" button so that it correctly loads.
If the number inside the span is less than 5, add a class to the span of badge-danger
If the number inside the span is less than 10, add a class to the span of badge-secondary
Otherwise, add a class to the span of badge-danger
```

my code is below, I do not know how to deal with nodelists nor the most efficient way to loop over them & make changes such as changing the class in this example.:

```js
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
      // Write your code here! Don't forget the above in later lessons.
      let lessThanFive = num => if (num < 5);
      lessThanTen = num => if (num < 10);
      let listItems = document.querySelectorAll('li');
      for (let i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
        let spanNumbers = listItems[i].lastChild.lastChild;
        if (spanNumbers.filter(lessThanFive)) {
            // add class of "badge=danger"
        }
        else if (spanNumbers.filter(lessThanTen)) {
            //add class of "badge-secondary"
        } else {
            //add class of "badge=secondary"
         }
      }
    })
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Agile <span class="badge">15</span></li>
  <li>Command Line <span class="badge">2</span></li>
  <li>HTML <span class="badge">8</span></li>
  <li>CSS <span class="badge">7</span></li>
  <li>JavaScript <span class="badge">11</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What code have you tried to use that didn't work, and what was the error? SO isn't a code writing service, so you will need to make an effort of at least trying.

Comment: I quit out of the tab & lost my code, but I will recreate it:

Comment: I added my code, sorry for the faux pas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simplified version:

Loop through the badges. Adding + before the variable will cast it to numeric. Then a basic if else statement, combined with adding a class.

```js
let badges = document.querySelectorAll('.badge');

badges.forEach(function(badge) {
  val = +badge.innerText;
  if(val < 5 || val > 10){
    badge.classList.add("badge-danger");
  }
  else{
     badge.classList.add("badge-secondary");
  }
})
```

```css
.badge-secondary{color:green}
.badge-danger{color:red}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Agile <span class="badge">15</span></li>
  <li>Command Line <span class="badge">2</span></li>
  <li>HTML <span class="badge">8</span></li>
  <li>CSS <span class="badge">7</span></li>
  <li>JavaScript <span class="badge">11</span></li>
</ul>

When you get to the page, press the "Run" button so that it correctly loads.
If the number inside the span is less than 5, add a class to the span of badge-danger
If the number inside the span is less than 10, add a class to the span of badge-secondary
Otherwise, add a class to the span of badge-danger
```

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated. The classList & add manipulations are new to me.

Comment: @Pensive_Knave I made a quick update, I misread the requirements. I accidently added the class to the list item not the span.